# Values from inner html children not being retrieved

Tags: javascript, html

I create dynamically a number of text labels and add them to the first html page and am trying to retrieve those values when the user moves to the second page. For some reason the html values are not being retrieved. I've been playing around with this for a while and have not had any luck.

```
var ReadingComprehensionExperiemnt = function(remaining){

psiTurk.showPage('stage1.html');

text = "Many years ago I went to Amsterdam as an art student, to be trained under the auspices of the then famous portrait painter Kruseman. Very soon I was admitted to the master's studio, and beheld with admiration the portraits of the distinguished personages he was painting at the time."
d3.select("#passage")
        .style("text-align","center")
        .style("font-size","25px")
        .style("font-weight","400")
        .style("margin","20px")
        .text(text);
$("#next").click(function () {
    var sel = document.getElementById('sentence');
    var numLines = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
    psiTurk.showPage('stage2.html');
    d3.select("#passage")
            .style("text-align","center")
            .style("font-size","18px")
            .style("font-weight","400")
            .style("margin","20px")
            .text(text);

        var elm = document.getElementById( 'user-input' );
        for (i=0;i<numLines;i++){
            var lab;
            if (i==0){
                lab="What:  ";
            } else{
                lab="Cause: ";
            }
            div = document.createElement( 'div' );
            div.innerHTML = `<center>${lab}<input id='textfield_${i}' type='text' value='' size="100"></center>`;
            elm.appendChild( div );         }

        $("#next2").click(function () {
                psiTurk.showPage('stage3.html');
                var data=[text,numLines];

                for (i=0;i<numLines;i++){
                    var name = "textfield_" + i;
                    var input = document.getElementById(name).value;
                    alert(input);

                }


    });

});

}
```

Comment: Your code sample doesn't allow to reproduce the error. Please submit additional code.

Comment: Create a code snippet or add some additional info which can be used to help you out.

Comment: Based on your description, it seems that you are fetching an element created in a previous page. In this case, '#textfield_0' may not exist anymore. Please provide full code.

Comment: @radscheit I updated the question with the full function. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @FabioMazano I updated the question with the full function. Thank you for the help

Comment: @thebrownkid I updated the question with the full function. Thank you for the help